# What is the package or reference for MimeReader?

Tags: mime, mimekit

I have been searching through the net for the package and reference required to use `MimeReader` but to no avail.

I imported `MimeKit` but `MimeReader` is not available.

Is the functionality depreciated or am I looking for the wrong keyword?

```
Usage: MimeReader mime = new MimeReader();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MimeReader is part of Microsoft.Exchange.Data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-api/aa579311(v=exchg.150)

There is no nuget package for this API.

I believe these assemblies are only available if you have the Microsoft Exchange SDK.

Update: MimeKit >= v3.0 now has a MimeReader class, but it does not have an identical API to the MimeReader in Microsoft.Exchange.Data